# Having problem creating maven artifacts in solr on Windows 7

Tags: java, maven, lucene, solr

I'm trying to build solr 4.0 snapshot in maven. Here are my steps:

1. Check out solr in d:\workspace\solr
2. download ant, unzip to d:\ant. set the ANT_HOME to d:\ant
3. download maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar (the latest version) to d:\ant\lib
4. in commandline, go to d:\workspace\solr\lucene
5. run command:
   ant generate-maven-artifacts

it gives the error:

```
D:\workspace\solr\lucene\common-build.xml:326: #
    ##########################################################################
      Maven ant tasks not found.

      Please download the Maven ant tasks JAR (maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar)
      from http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/download.html and add it to your
      $HOME/.ant/lib/ directory, or to your $ANT_HOME/lib/ directory, or
      to your $CLASSPATH, or add "-lib /path/to/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar"
      to the ant command.
    ##########################################################################

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I tried running:

```
ant -lib d:\ant\lib generate-maven-artifacts
```

it's the same error.

running ant alone will build solr without problem.

Environment setting:

```
D:\workspace\solr\lucene>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

D:\workspace\solr\lucene>mvn --version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 12:16:01-0700)
Java version: 1.6.0_24
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

Can any one help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run ant like this:

```
 ant -lib d:\ant\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar generate-maven-artifacts
```

Classpath adds need file references (not directory references). You can also add it like so:

```
 SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;d:\ant\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
 ant generate-maven-artifacts
```

Comment: same problem even after using your way...I remember it worked on my machine before, but don't know why it's failing now. Does ant have any caching data so I can remove them and start from a clean ant ?

Comment: you can just delete the ant folder and re-download it.

Comment: OK, switching to Linux fixed the problem. I just created a ubuntu virtual machine, installed ant there, then share the same folder on Windows and run the same command. It works like a charm...